# How to print Triangular numbers using For Loop while also printing numbers prior to input in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, math, input, printing

So one of my school project has me wanting to print out triangular numbers, where they ask for a prompt (input) of how many rows of dots i want to print out and it would print out the triangular number, while also printing out the triangular numbers that were less than that prompt

I tried using a For Loop and I did successfully manage to get the system to print out the amount of numbers displayed, but for some reason it just only printed out whats needed in the prompt

What is should be:

```
how many lines you want on your triangle?: 3
1.0
3.0
6.0
```

How it's being printed out:

```
how many lines you want on your triangle?: 3
15.0
15.0
15.0
```

The code:

```py
j = int(input('how many lines you want on your triangle??????: '))
num1 = 1

for i in range(0, j):
  num1 =((j**2)+j)/(2) 
  print(num1)
```

I'm aware I got the formula wrong, but i still want to know why it's only printing one number

Comment: Use i instead of j in your loop

Comment: For any given value of *j* your formula will always produce the same result

Comment: j = 3, therefore ((j**2)+j)/(2) = 15. I think you meant to put i in there somewhere

Comment: For an input value of 3 your code will **not** output 15.0 three times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate `num1` as a function of `j`, but loop over `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it but forgot to use the various values in the range.

```
j = int(input('how many lines do you want on your triangle?: '))

for i in range(1, j+1):
    print((i*i+i)//2)
```

**Console:**

```
how many lines do you want on your triangle?: 5
1
3
6
10
15
```